# FormView not updating when using BLL and DAL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I haven't worked with formview in a while and this one is not ordinary in a way that it does not uses ObjectDataSource, rather it used the BLL classes for CRUD operation. It does not update. Can someone look at this and point out the obvious?

Actually the update_Click method never fires. I've also tried adding a onupdating event but that also did to fire.

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvContactDetails_Mod" runat="server" DataKeyNames="memberid" EnableViewState="false"
  OnDataBound="fvContactDetails_Mod_OnDataBound" >
  <EditItemTemplate>                        
     <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="formlabel"><label for="fname">First Name:</label></td>
          <td class="formvalue">
             <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFname" CssClass="txtfield" text='<%# Bind("firstname") %>' />
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtFname" ErrorMessage="First Name is required." ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ToolTip="First Name is required."   ValidationGroup="CreateUserForm">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="formlabel"><label for="lname">Last Name:</label></td>
          <td class="formvalue">
             <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLname" CssClass="txtfield"  text='<%# Bind("lastname") %>'/>
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtLname" ErrorMessage="Last Name is required." ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ToolTip="Last Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserForm">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p><Club:RolloverButton ID="update" runat="server" Text="Update Registration" OnClick="update_Click" /></p>
          </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </EditItemTemplate>
   </asp:FormView

protected void update_Click(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();

    try
    {
        TextBox  txtFname = (TextBox)fvContactDetails_Mod.FindControl("txtFname");
        TextBox  txtLname = (TextBox)fvContactDetails_Mod.FindControl("txtLname");
        DropDownList  ddlRankid = (DropDownList)fvContactDetails_Mod.FindControl("ddlRankid");


        MemberInformation update = new MemberInformation();
        if (update.UpdateMemberInfo((Guid)user.ProviderUserKey,
            txtFname.Text,
            txtLname.Text,))
        {

        ContactStatus.Text = "Details have been updated sucessfully.";
        ContactStatus.ControlStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ContactStatus.Text = "Error updating contact details: " + ex.Message;
        ContactStatus.ControlStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you disable ViewState (which you apparently did), you have to rebind the data-bound control with the exact same data on the Postback so that it can be recreated to the same state as before and its events can actually fire (in your case the update_Click).

Without seeing your databinding code here, this is just a shot in the dark, but I guess you do not rebind your control on Postback or rebind it with (slightly) different data, which causes your event to not being fired.

Enable ViewState or, if you don't want to, make sure your data binding happens correctly on Postback. If that doesn't help, please provide the code where you bind the FormView.

Comment: Not knowing a whole lot about formview, I've added an ItemTemplate with the same set up as the Edit template and suddenly it worked.